# undefined method `<' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, class

I have just started learning Ruby and while doing a switch case problem i encountered this error.

```
puts "Enter your percentage"
pr = gets.to_i
case pr
    when (pr < 40)
        puts "He gets a D"
    when (pr >= 40 & pr < 60)
        puts "He gets a C"
    when (pr >=60 & pr<80)
        puts "He gets a B"
    when (pr >= 80)
        puts "He gets an A"
    else
        puts "he gets an A"
end
```

When i input 85 i got that error. Can anyone suggest me some change.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `case pr` → `case` and `&` → `&&` in both places.

Comment: `pr.between?(40, 60)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error sounds give you your answer.

The `undefined method` is `<`, so your value go inside your first case. It seems your value is a `boolean` which is equal to `true`.

Comment: Yup i got that ...  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use `&` for *and*-ing instead of `&&`, but in this case, operator precedence kills your. While

```
 a > b && c < d
```

is interpreted as

```
(a > b) && (c < d)
```

the expression

```
a > b & c < d
```

is taken as

```
(a > (b & c)) < d
```

which means:

- calculate first the binary *and* of b and c (which already doesn't make that much sense in your case), yielding some integer.
- see wheather a is greater than this, yielding a bool.
- see wheather this bool is larger than d, which yields an exception.

Have a look at [the operator precedence table](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence) for Ruby.